# Try to mimic mac default screen capture behavior (Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of mac default screen capture app, specifically  CMD+SHIFT+5.
It covers entire screen(s) with shadow and make the screenshot area clear.
Also, it won't allow the shadowed area to move.

For example, I created NSWindow with 0.5 alpha, gray, .styleMask = .borderless and isMovable = false.
Normal user unable to move that around, but using BetterTouchTool, you can move the window.
This behavior doesn't allowed to the default screen capture app.

Could anyone teach me how to mimic the default app's behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to use Hopper and found out it looks like using CGSNewWindowWithOpaqueShape. But, I really don't know how to use that function in Swift.